# mongoose saving new field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have a school object which is a mongoose model, and i want to make school.days[dateNow]=1,
where days is a mongoose Object, and has not been set till now. i get this error : "Cannot set property '2014-05-02' of undefined"

```
 school.days[dateNow] = 1;
 school.save();
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 0):

It says you that school.days is undefined and property cannot be assigned to it. This is JS issue solely and has no concern with Mongo. To fix this first check if you have school.days object and initialize it if not.

```
if (!school.days) school.days = {};
school.days[whatever] = 1;
```

However, a better solution might be to create empty `days` when you **first** insert the document to the database. So that instead of creating new paths you only amend them. This results in much better performance. For more details read this [article on time series data](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb), I'm sure you find it helpful.